# Oracle Apex - Creating Web Services

Tags: web-services, soap, oracle11g, widget, oracle-apex

I have developed an application in Oracle Application Express 4.0.

**I now want to create a SOAP Web Service for my application. Are there any APEX 4.0 widgets or plugins that will help me with this ?**

**Has any one tried to create a web service out of their application in Apex. If so what would be the pros and cons in doing so.**

I am fairly new to APEX . Appreciate your comments / suggestions !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mohan,

refer video https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:3620318427055:::24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PROD_SECTION_GRP_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:5815,,24#prettyPhoto

which shows how to create SOAP web services